# I am un-able to type in any text field on my website. Nor can any users

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, textbox

I have no idea how or why this is happening, but all text fields on my website can not be typed in.

I seem to have bad luck when asking questions here so I would ask you just go to [https://contest.faucetastic.fun](http://contest.faucetastic.fun) and attempt to login. Any info/guesses or direction on this issue would be much appreciated as I legit have not the foggiest.

I've looked through possible settings as to why this is happening, but I just don't have the experience to find out what happened.

I've been wondering why I've had no sign-ups with all the ads I've ran

**UPDATE**:

So while I'm in my admin panel and on theme customizer I noticed I was logged in on my site itself, I clicked log out and it took me to the admin log in screen for WP. Then went back to my theme customizer and was logged in again. I clicked log out once again but this time my screen went white and did not recover.

I'm sorry that not so experienced to give more deffinate descriptions, but I'm in a serious bind here so I truly do appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried to use a different theme with buddypress? Is the hestia theme buddypress compatibel? Have inspected the HTML and CSS with a browser? -> e.g. Firefox right-click `Inspect element (Q)` and check what css could cause it? Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If I knew a better way to ask it, I would have, I read up, been researching for hours. im not a coder or back end guy at all, im a visualist so I did the best that I could. And everything was working yesterday, I haven't changed anything today either

Comment: On visiting site, Avast AV claims there is  a threat and states it has prevented crypto currency mining malware being installed on my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after some very frugal and stunning efforts from [WPMU Dev](https://premium.wpmudev.org/).  It was established that the NES Emulator Known as [Retro Game Emulator](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/retro-game-emulator/) has several flaws, one of which locks up all text fields on a site.
The amazing folks at WPMU Dev even went as far as reaching out to him to see if he was either aware or cared about the fault. As it turns out, He really doesn't seem to give two s**** about.

-=- And to the user that mentioned the miner. I removed that Long before your comment which concerns me. I will head there now and run a few tests

**<>TID BIT TO ADD<> + <>NEW QUESTION<>**

If any of you have used the [nesbox](http://nesbox.com) before, you already know that its both A: Amazing, but B: missing some U.I components. 
Now, From the back end of the retro game emulator, you can easily upload files directly into it with a drop down tab. Then on the front end, users drop the same menu, but instead it displays the games uploaded that can be played.
So my continued question now is, would it be possible to add that feature to the nesbox to make it both easier for wordpress webmasters to install, and give higher functionality to front end users. 
I know this may intale a long answer, so, this is just for thought :)
should you have an explosive thought tho. please write er down ;)

<>I WILL START A NEW THREAD SOON FOR THIS<>

Just gonna jump to tic80 and talk to nesbox man

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I set the color of the text to black.. and it showed. your css has the color of the text in the input elements set to white or matches the box ..

I would put

```
input[type='text']{ color: black; }
```

in style.css

or in the js

```
$( "form input:text" ).css({
  color: "black",

});
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, so I added the additional css to my theme and I can now see the blinking cursor but nothing types in and the cursor doesn't move. maybe its opera's fault, cause if you can type but i can't, thats my next guess
<>UPDATE<>
so I logged in on MS Edge and still couldn't type, nor on google chrome

Comment: may I ask what browser you are using? cause everyone i get to try and type in that field is un-successful. you are the only one so far who has been able to and i am just baffled as to how

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry about your website. You are right I went back to test again and it  was autofill. So I can't type in it but if you try autofill it works. It definitely is troubling. I'm using firefox and still haven't found the real issue but your css was one of them. cause all the input fields were all set to white for some reason